# Tiny Elasticsearch like search library in ruby?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, search, full-text-search, information-retrieval

Is there an alternative to Elasticsearch? I am looking for something lightweight and tiny. Some sort of Ruby library would be ideal. For example, if I don't need to run an application to do the job but instead using that library I can search YAML or JSON files for matching text etc. And based on match score returns the sorted list.

Example here would make it clear.
Let's say I have a single YAML file with array of strings E.g

```
values: 
  - “some nice text here”
  - “this is another sentence” 
  - “some nice”
  - “nice text here”
```

So now if I search for “some nice text here” the first line should come on top but also there is a slight similarity with the last two lines, so the search results should return as follows:

1. some nice text here
2. nice text here
3. some nice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), come to mind but they're not small. Hell even using PostgreSQL until you really need to scale is fine (and you'll know when you need to scale) and it's probably already baked into your stack.

If your needs are to search YAML files, you could easily write your own naive approac

There's also https://github.com/mezis/fuzzily but it might require some updating.